# On periodic orbits of a discrete dynamic system

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

Let $f: D \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous with $f(D) \subset D$ and let $x_0$ be a $n$-periodic atractor point of $f$. Show that every point of the cycle $\{ x_0, f(x_0),\dots,f^{n-1}(x_0) \}$ is also an $n$-periodic atractor point of $f$.

I tried using the definition of continuity in $\mathbb{R}$, but I always end up using 3 points of the cycle and I don't know how to solve this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: A periodic point is attractive only if the products of the derivatives at every point on the cycle has an absolute value less than 1.  But you get the same product regardless of what point on the cycle you start on. It follows that if one in the cycle is attractive, then so are the rest.

Comment: I know that, but I can only assume continuity, not derivability. Our proffessor explicitly said that we couldn't use the derivative criterion. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What is your definition of attractor?

Comment: An atractor of a function g is a point so that there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ so that for every $y \in (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$, you have $\lim_{k \to \infty} g^k(y) = x$.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially, you have per assumptions continuous functions $F,G$, here more precisely $F=f^k$, $G=f^{n-k}$, with a cycle $F(x_*)=y_*$ and $G(y_*)=x_*$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $x_*$ so that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}(G\circ F)^{\circ m}(x)=x_* ~~\text{ for all }~~ x\in U. $$

Now take $V=G^{-1}(U)$ and observe $$(F\circ G)^{\circ m}=F\circ(G\circ F)^{\circ(m-1)}\circ G$$ to find a similar limit property for all $y\in V$ being propagated towards $y_*$.

This redistribution of the compositions means that an $y=y_0\in V$ gets mapped to some $x=x_0\in U$, and the sequences $x_m$, $y_m$ are connected by $x_m=G(x_m)$ and $y_{m+1}=F(x_m)$. Thus convergence of one series is equivalent to the convergence of the other.